# Code exiting after calling await client.ExecuteAsync(request)

Tags: c#, async-await, server-sent-events

I am consuming an API and uploading data and check any update using Stream (Server sent events). Below is my code. I have created a async method and also called await while executing my request. where code is exiting and not proceeding to next step.

```
public static async void ResponseDataStream(string url, string Token)
{

    RestResponse DataResponse = null;
    var start = System.DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ");
    try
    {
        var options = new RestClientOptions(Settings.Default.API_BaseURL)
        {
            MaxTimeout = -1,
        };
        var client = new RestClient(options);
        var request = new RestRequest(Settings.Default.StreamURL, Method.Get);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "XYZ";
        //request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("source-system", "ZZZ");
        request.AddHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        request.AddParameter("start", start);
        DataResponse = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
        ClsLogger.LogEvent("Reading Stream response." +DataResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode);
        if (DataResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
        {
            ClsLogger.LogEvent("Successfully connected to stream and reading content of the stream");
            var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(DataResponse.Content);
            ClsLogger.LogEvent("Data Stream Result is: " + result);
            if (result != null)
            {
                UploadData(Settings.Default.UploadURL, Settings.Default.FilePath, Token.ToString());
            }
        }
        else { }

    }
    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
}
```

Can someone please help what I am missing here? Or why my code is exiting immediate after await function calls.

Comment: `async void` is a bug to begin with. Change it to `async Task` and await the method. `async void` is only meant for asynchronous event handlers. Such methods can't be awaited and the caller will exit before the method has a chance to complete. On top of that, the code never logs any error responses so there's no way to know if the server returned an error

Comment: Thanks i will try after making that change as well thanks. Logging is there just for pasting it here i removed that error logging stuff.

Comment: The general recommendation is to [avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void "Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming"), unless it's an event handler.